# Wi-FI issue with lubuntu update from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, debian, lubuntu

i have an old 2010 laptop and i upgraded it from lubuntu 18.10 to  19.04.
Basically it works quite well but i have an issue with the wifi, even if i'm connected to my home network it says that i'm offline and my default wifi manager does not seem to work. what should i do?
Notes: 
1) i used the alternate 64 bit installer because my Laptop does not read the official 64 bit iso.

Comment: What make and model is your laptop?

Comment: 18.10 and 19.04 are both interim releases.  Those don't get a lot of testing so it's possible that it's a bug if it isn't a missing driver, and the support period is very short.  Try loading the stable, LTS release (18.04; a live session might be enough), just to see if the problem goes away.